# Not reading a column and data when I see the column in the debugger

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read something from a SQLDataReader.. now it errors saying "Invalid attempt to read when no data present".  But when I go into the debugger (attached pictures).  I clearly see the column and the data I want to read.  I made sure MyStatColumn has "p_era" in there.  I've tried 3 ways of reading the column but they all error.... can anyone help?

[image]

```
            string MyStatColumn;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_sql, connection))
                {
                    using (RecordSet = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (!RecordSet.HasRows)
                        {
                            return "No Data";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MyStatRankLeague = RecordSet[MyStatColumn + "_LeagueRank"].ToString();  //errors
                            MyStatRankOverall = RecordSet[MyStatColumn + "_MLBRank"].ToString();  //errors
                            MyStatRankOverall = AppendRankSuffix(MyStatRankOverall);  //errors
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nead to call RecordSet.Read() before you can try to read data from it.  When Readers are first opened they are positioned before the first record and require at least one call to .Read to advance them to the first record in the result set.

Comment: ahhh i figured it was something simple.  okay will try right now

Comment: You can even use it as a condition `if (RecordSet.Read())` ... -- read your data. Instead of `if (RecordSet.HasRows)` I mean

Comment: thanks guys it works! was stuck on that for so long pulling my hair out lol.. thanks again.  will give credit when the 10 minutes pass

Comment: Don't feel bad.  I'm sure every one of us has forgotten to call .Read at one point or another.

Comment: first time going this route, usually use LINQ -.-  thanks again!